# Broken SELECT in Sql Server Compact 3.5 SP2?

Tags: sql-server-compact

I'm looking for a cause of a really strange case of SQL Server Compact db corruption. The case is that in a .NET Compact Framework app that we are running every once in a while we get into a situation where the following statement returns no rows

```
select * from order_item where id = '043740d1-c6d0-4fd4-ae84-fdb9218f8b81'
```

while

```
select * from order_item where id LIKE '043740d1-c6d0-4fd4-ae84-fdb9218f8b81'
```

returns one. Actually, when you select all rows from the table you can see that this row indeed exists in the db. The id column is uniqueidentifier, so it's not related to casing etc.

In any case, when I run the sdf file through Repair in SSMS, the first query starts returning the correct row.

I can only guess that the problem is related to some sort of index corruption - maybe it gets out of sync with the actual data store. Neither the app nor SSMS gives any sign of DB corruption - no exceptions, no messageboxes whatsoever.

Anyway, I can't really get to the root cause of this. I think it might have to do with modifying the db from different threads (at some points we may have 2 threads working on the db), but I thought this shouldn't be an issue.

Any idea what might cause this sort of issue?

UPDATE:
As @Catcall mentioned dropping the index fixed the issue, so it seems it's related to an out-of synch index. I think it's likely happening when the row is deleted - the index gets updated but the table row isn't for some reason.

Comment: What is the data type on the `order_item` column?

Comment: You could isolate index issues by dropping the index.

Comment: Does the database come from a desktop app/server, then it is vital that you use a recent version of SQL Server Compact on the device

Comment: @Gromer its uniqueidentifier

Comment: @Catcall thanks. That actually fixed the issue, so the problem is in fact caused by invalid index. I'll update the question.

Comment: @ErikEJ The db is created locally on the device.

Comment: @MichałDrozdowicz: I edited my comment into an answer. You might want to create your own answer with more detail about how you test or fix the indexing problem. You can accept your own answer, too.

Answer (score 2):

> I can only guess that the problem is related to some sort of index
>   corruption - maybe it gets out of sync with the actual data store.

You could isolate index issues by just dropping the index. That will slow down some or all of the queries that access that table, but if the problem goes away, you know for certain that the index was the source of the problem.

But even if the index is the source of your problem, it's not the *root cause* of your problem. To my way of thinking, the root cause is quite likely to be in Microsoft's code. An index that doesn't match the data is one of those things the database shouldn't allow. And if it happens, you should see big, waving red flags.

You can verify and and try to repair a SQL Server CE database in code.  I'm not sure whether this exercises the same code you'd use by trying to repair through SSMS. (I'd hope so, but I know that hope doesn't scale well.)

[How to: Verify and Repair a SQL Server Compact Edition Database (Programmatically)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172420%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

> I think it might have to do with modifying the db from different
>   threads (at some points we may have 2 threads working on the db), but
>   I thought this shouldn't be an issue.

Documentation for .NET 3 [SqlCEConnection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

I *think* you're safe if each thread uses a separate connection. I could be wrong.

Comment: That works, but it's not an acceptable solution, especially since the column is the PK of the table.

Comment: @MichałDrozdowicz: Updated answer.